# Material UI Nested lists using recursive render is not working with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm working on a project in which I need a sidebar with nested lists created with material UI, if I go to demo and copy the nested list code it's all fine but it comes with alot of code duplication. So after some digging I found recursive rendering function [gist](https://gist.github.com/nkvenom/bf7b1adfe982cb47dee3) which is written with classes. I'm using react hooks and the function logic is not working as expected.

**Problem:**
I have 3 level navigation, A parent, then child and child contains more items (grandchildren to parent). So when I click on the parent everything is fine children items appears, but when I click any of the children element the whole list closes.

**here is my Code:**

```
// useState hook with empty object as an initial Value

const [open1, setOpen1] = React.useState({});

// this method sets the current state of a menu item i.e whether it is in expanded or collapsed or a collapsed state

const handleClick = (param) => {
        setOpen1(prevState => ({[param]: !prevState[param]}));
    };

// if the menu item doesn't have any child, this method simply returns a clickable menu item that redirects to any location and if there is no child this method uses recursion to go until the last level of children and then returns the item by the first condition.

function nestedMenu(items) {

        return items.map((nav) => {
            if (!nav.children) {
                return (
                    <div key={nav.id}>
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemText primary={nav.name} />
                        </ListItem>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            return (
                <div key={nav.id}>
                    <ListItem button onClick={()=>handleClick(nav.name)}>
                        <ListItemText primary={nav.name} />
                        {open1[nav.name] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                    </ListItem>
                    <Collapse in={open1[nav.name] } timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                        <List component="div" disablePadding>
                          { nestedMenu(nav.children)}
                        </List>
                    </Collapse>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
```

After that I'm calling the `nestedMenu` function with json data as parameter in my return method

`<List>
  {nestedMenu(Links.items)}
</List>`

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong in all this, I have been working my head out to locate the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any hooks in your code. And what is `setOpen1`?

Comment: updated my question and included the hook definition, `setOpen1` is the function to update the state of hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you change the whole open1 object :

```
const handleClick = (param) => {
      setOpen1(prevState => ({[param]: !prevState[param]}));
};
```

for example if u have `{p1:true, p2:false}` and execute handkeClick('p1'),
open1 will be `{p1:false}`.
you need to keep the other members of open1 unchange and just update the one you want :

```
const handleClick = (param) => {
      setOpen1(prevState => 
          retrun {...prevState ,[param]: !prevState[param]}
      );
};
```

Comment: OMG, yessss! that's it, we always have to do it with hooks, a stupid mistake I did.

Thanks alot